# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined webpack with telegram

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, telegram

I am trying to use telegram node modules (telegram-js, telegram-mt-node, telegram-tl-node) inside webpack on a client web app.

currently I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

the error is pointing to this line:

```
module.exports = require("crypto");
```

I did a global search through my node_modules and "crypto" is only found inside webpack and less node modules, not telegram. I cant find a line anywhere that actually matches the line it references.

In the webpack build file, require() is normally changed to _webpack_require(). So it seems webpack got confused during the build process.

Here is my webpack.config

```
    var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var libraryName = 'webapp';
var version = '1.0';

var config = {
  entry: './app-src/proto.index.js',
  output: { 
    path: __dirname+"/build/lib/", 
    publicPath: "/build/",
    filename: libraryName+'.all.js',
    library: libraryName,
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
      fs: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      crypto: 'empty'
    },
  resolve: {
    root: [
       path.resolve('./app-src/'),
       path.resolve('../cmn/'),
    ]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" },
        // JS and JSX
        {
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                retainLines: true
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }
    ]
  },

};

module.exports = config;
```

telegram-mt-node, telegram-tl-node have both been written with browsify in mind, like making use of requirish for example. I have removed all references to requirish and fixed the require issues webpack had during the build process. The error I am running into is during runtime on the browser.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that telegram node_modules were written for browserify not webpack. Switched to the browserify build manager got things going